# Can't convert flac files to ogg using Sound Converter

Tags: 14.04, ogg-vorbis, soundconverter

I have one really annoying problem, when I try to convert a flac file to ogg it returns an error message which says that a "General stream error was found" in every file. It does create the outpout files but they are empty.

Have I missed something, is this a bug?

This does not affect other file types, I was able to convert a bunch of mp3 's to ogg without any problem.

Comment: You could try to convert files on the command line with the `oggenc` command.  That would help find out if the problem was in oggenc, soundconverter, or your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg or avconv for this task.

To convert an audio file to ogg format issue the command `ffmpeg -i *inputfile* *outputfile.ogg*

as I recall `avconv` has the same syntax.

You can use this approach to convert virtually any audio or video format to any virtually other. There are switches that you can use to resample the audio at different bitrates and frequencies. For more detail see the [ffmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) or [avconv docs.](https://libav.org/documentation/avconv.html) Depending on what you are converting you might need to install restricted formats with `apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with soundconverter in 22.04, the solution for me was to install soundKonverter which worked fine. I guess it's a bug in soundconverter.